# Horizontal angular rotation speed

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics

Below is the question I'm not sure I've properly solved.

A smooth bead of mass 100g is threaded on a light inextensible string of length 70 cm. The string has one end attached to a fixed point A and the other to a fixed point B 50 cm vertically below A. The bead moves in a horizontal circle about the line AB with a constant angular speed of $\omega$ rad/s, and the string taut. If the bead is at a point C on the string with AC = 40 cm, find the value of $\omega$  and the tension in the string.

Because its a 3-4-5 triangle, I found the horizontal rotation plane to be 0.18m above B, and therefore 0.32m below A.  The radius is then 0.24m.  I found this by extending AC to 6.25m.  I then resolve the vertical and horizontal forces and found $\omega$ to be 4.88 rad/s.  I`m however not sure about this answer as books says 16.9, 4.9N.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an image to help.

[image: horizontal_rotation_plane]

Comment: Could you add a picture or a more detailed description. I am especially stuck on this sentence "The bead moves in a horizontal circle about the line AB".

Comment: @maxmilgram, I hope that helps

Comment: I don't get your answer or the answer in the book. I'll post my free body diagram in the answer because it won't post in the comments.

Comment: See revised answer, same as the book.

Comment: @Phil H, thanks for confirming the books answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I had the resultant of the strings at the wrong angle. Now corrected I get the same result as the book.

This should be a comment but a diagram won't post to the comments. Take a look and see if you agree.

[image]